# ack ignore files matching a path in conjunction with positive path match

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ack

I want to do a command that searches all .js and .php files, but ignores paths with "Thirdparty/" and "data.js" in them.

```
ack -il -G '(\.js|\.php)' 'my search string'
```

I tried -v but it seems to inverse all -G operators, not just the preceeding operator:

```
ack -il -G '(\.js|\.php)' -G '(Thirdparty|data\.js)' -v 'my search string'
```

I want to ignore ./Thirdparty paths and also ./data.js path but match all over .js and .php files.

Answer (score 0):

-v inverts the pattern ("my search string" in this  case) and not the filename regex.
With more recent versions of ack an --invert-file-match option takes care of your requirement. The following should work with ack 1.96.

```
ack -il -G '(\.js|\.php)' --invert-file-match -G '(Thirdparty|data\.js)' 
'my search string'
```